# Jenkins Throwing error while building .net project

Tags: visual-studio, jenkins, msbuild, nuget-package-restore

I'm trying to build a .net projects on jenkins. It is throwing error saying nuget packages are missing. I'm unable to get which packages are missing exactly.

[image]

when im going inside the visual studio and trying to build the project, it is building properly without any error.

My other .net projects are building absolutely fine on jenkins. Only this project is throwing errors.

Comment: Enable automatic package restore for the solution?

Comment: @stijin  thanks. actually i didnot about restoring packages so im using manual windows batch command to restore all nuget packages required for solution to build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

applying manual windows batch coomand to restore nuget package required by solution

[image]

adding this build step before building the solution so it will restore all the dependencies required by solution.